# EXCEL custom functions can use ajax？

Tags: javascript, excel

**What do I want to achieve：**
I want to call the interface in a custom function,Use the data returned by the interface to calculate.

**actual result：**
Custom functions cannot compute the correct result,always get 0.

This is my function.js code：

```
function add(first, second) {
  ajax_web({
    api: API_ENTITY.LOGIN,
    data: {
      domain: '01',
      user: 'dev',
      pass: 'shijinimda',
    },
  }).then(function (data) {
    return first + second;
  })
}
```

Did I do something wrong?If you need more documents, please ask me.

thanks a lot

Comment: how is `add` being used?

Comment: I created the project through Yeoman. The ADD function called this way：=CONTOSO.ADD(1,1)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/excel-tutorial-create-custom-functions?tabs=excel-windows#create-a-custom-function-that-requests-data-from-the-web